# Put salt on/ Add salt to fruits

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

1. Put salt on fruits.

a) Is this sentence correct? Do we use 'put' with salt/ spices?

2. **Add** salt **to** fruits.

a) Same question. Is this one correct/ more natural?

b) I need clarification about the preposition as well. Do we always say 'add to?' Or is it also correct to say 'put to' in sentences like these?

Comment: I am not so sure about using "put" in this case. More colloquial use is "add a pinch of sugar/salt/turmeric/pepper/etc. to anything". But I can say one thing, "put salt to" is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you are served at the table you may

> Put salt on your eggs.

When you are cooking you may

> Add salt to your stew.

(Salt on fruit is less common than on eggs or in stew.)

Comment: I see. So you 'add salt to something' so the salt is in the food and you 'put salt to something' so it's on the food, meaning you put it after cooking it. If that's the case, would it be wrong to say 'add salt' when you're at the table and feel like your food needs more salt?

Comment: At the table you probably would not usually _say_ either. Neither would be wrong. I might add salt to my soup (and stir it in) put put salt on (not to) my eggs. The difference is between "in" and "on".

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the preposition, it is never "put (thing) **to** (destination)". (OK, almost never: you can put something *to the side*, but that is a special expression.)

"Put salt **on** your eggs", "Put salt **onto** your eggs", "Put salt **in** your stew", and "Put salt **into** your stew" are all grammatically correct.

"Add" is a typical verb used in recipes. By default, "add" goes with "to": "Add salt **to** your stew". "Into" would also be correct, though perhaps more specific than necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is there any difference between 'put on' and 'put in'? I mean when you're talking about a boiled egg would it sound wrong to say "put some salt IN the egg." And what about when making scrambled eggs, can you use both?- "put some salt ON/IN it."

Comment: IN for inside or mixed in, ON for the outside. With scrambled eggs either is fine (though ON suggests it is added on top rather than mixed in).